# Weil restriction over integers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

If we have a finite (possibly ramified) map of Dedekind domains $f:D\to D'$ and a finite type affine $D'$-scheme $X'$ is there a functorial way to produce a finite type affine $D$-scheme $X$ that behaves similarly to Weil restriction?

Comment: Weil restriction exists and has the usual properties for any finite flat map, so it exists in your situation. See, for example, Section 7.6 of the book "Neron Models" by Bosch et al.

Comment: @naf: This would be a good answer